# I am trying to insert json into a postgres (pgadmin4) table using python 3 but I keep getting null

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a Postgres table in pgadmin4 and it has 2 columns. ID (big serial, not null) and json (json). I keep getting the value null in my json column when trying to insert my json data from it which I got by doing a get request. Under the column settings for json I have not selected 'not null'.

I am still learning; my code might be a bit messy.

```
import os
import requests
import psycopg2
import json


def get_request():
    token = os.environ['TOKEN']
    url = os.environ['URL']
    payload = {}
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }

    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    result = (response.text.encode('utf8'))
    parsed = json.loads(result)
    print(parsed)
    print(type(parsed))
    

def db_connection(parsed):
    con = psycopg2.connect(
        host=os.environ['HOST'],
        dbname=os.environ['DBNAME'],
        user=os.environ['USER'],
        password=os.environ['PASSWORD'],
        port=os.environ['PORT'])
    print("CONNECTED")


    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO ingest.occupations_group (json) VALUES (%s)", (parsed,))
    con.commit()

    cur.close()
    con.close()

get_request()
db_connection(get_request())
```

And when I run the code for some reason it display the results twice. I did not include the all of the api results as it is super long.

```
{'@odata.context': 'https://apis.burning-glass.com/v3.5/ontology/$metadata#occupationgroups',   'value': [{'id': 2, 'ontologyIRI': 
<class 'dict'>
{'@odata.context': 'https://apis.burning-glass.com/v3.5/ontology/$metadata#occupationgroups',   'value': [{'id': 2, 'ontologyIRI':
<class 'dict'>
CONNECTED

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: pgadmin4 is a tool for working with PostgreSQL.  It is not a flavor of PostgreSQL.  It doesn't seem relevant to your question.

Comment: Are you sure you are running this script as posted here?  The `cur.execute()` should be throwing an exception because you are passing a `dict` where json is expected.

Comment: @jjanes thanks, I just wanted to include as much detail as possible.

Comment: @MikeOrganek yes that is the code I am running. So I it should not be a dict? Thanks for your help, newbie here.

Comment: On your `cur.execute()` line, try `(json.dumps(parsed),)` as your bind parameters.

Comment: @MikeOrganek unfortunately that didn't work. The output in the json column slightly changed from [null] to null

Comment: Please add `return parsed` to the end of `get_request()`.  Sorry--I should have edited your post to format the code up front.

Comment: omg yes! @MikeOrganek that was it! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me, this has been driving me crazy for hours.